# Match and replace subexpression

Tags: replacement, expression-manipulation

I would like to replace the expresion $(n1-1)$ to $z1$ in following:

```
2*n1*p[n1-1,n2]
```

> 2*(z1+1)*p[z1,n2]

I have tried `Replace`, `ReplaceAll`, `/.`, `//.` but nothing seems to be working. Only part inside $p[n1-1, n2]$ is replaced. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `(* stuff *) /. n1 -> z1 +1` doesn't do what you want?

Answer (score 6):

If you type:

```
2 n1 p[n1-1, n2] /. {n1 -> z1 +1}
```

then the answer is:

```
2 (1 + z1) p[z1, n2]
```

This is shorthand for the function:

```
ReplaceAll[2 n1 p[n1 - 1, n2], n1 -> z1+1]
```

which explicitly uses the rule (in the second argument) to change the first argumemnt.

Comment: Ah strange asterixes appear in your answer. I figured I'd (propose to) edit them, but you made an edit as well in the meantime. Oh well, please fix the asterixes :).

Comment: thanks Jacob -- I don't know where they came from...

Comment: No problem, I think they came from the original problem statement, that has now been fixed by Istvan Zachar :). Hm.. I think Maria was trying to also replace the n1 that appears outside the function p, so I think this is probably not what she wants..

Comment: I just realized that and changed it. But now I realize this is exactly what JM suggested... sorry JM.. I'm happy to delete and give to you...

Comment: Yesterday I posted the silliest answer only to delete it a minute later, I can relate :P

Answer (score 4):

If $n1$ is set initially, when any function that contains this variable is entered, the conversion will be automatic.

```
n1 = z1 + 1; 
2*n1*p[n1 - 1, n2]
```